# Opencart: multi-language banners

Tags: multilingual, opencart

I have an Opencart store with multiple languages. Banners can contain only one picture (irrespective of the language chosen), but we design banners for each language.

Is there a way I can do this? I don't mind a hack (I can change / program any file, I don't care), but I'd like my users to be able to upload multiple photos.

Answer (score 1):

Give this opencart plugin a try, it has both manual install options and vqmod options, I have tried it and it works.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6451

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the new Multi-language banner. It's also for free, new and do it's job, and supported for the new version 1.5.6. You can find it on two places, the own opencart module section http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15049&sort=e.date_added&order=DESC&page=2 or in the creator's webpage http://www.alzoco.com/BannerMultiLanguage. It only has manual installation.